# get world phone codes list

Tags: android, phone-number

I need to get all world phone codes in my android application. Somebody know how I can do it ? I mean something like [here](http://countrycode.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new Raw XML file with the following content:

```
<string-array name="CountryCodes" >
    <item>93,AF</item>
    <item>355,AL</item>
    <item>213,DZ</item>
    <item>376,AD</item>
    <item>244,AO</item>
    <item>672,AQ</item>
    <item>54,AR</item>
    <item>374,AM</item>
    <item>297,AW</item>
    <item>61,AU</item>
    <item>43,AT</item>
    <item>994,AZ</item>
    <item>973,BH</item>
    <item>880,BD</item>
    <item>375,BY</item>
    <item>32,BE</item>
    <item>501,BZ</item>
    <item>229,BJ</item>
    <item>975,BT</item>
    <item>591,BO</item>
    <item>387,BA</item>
    <item>267,BW</item>
    <item>55,BR</item>
    <item>673,BN</item>
    <item>359,BG</item>
    <item>226,BF</item>
    <item>95,MM</item>
    <item>257,BI</item>
    <item>855,KH</item>
    <item>237,CM</item>
    <item>1,CA</item>
    <item>238,CV</item>
    <item>236,CF</item>
    <item>235,TD</item>
    <item>56,CL</item>
    <item>86,CN</item>
    <item>61,CX</item>
    <item>61,CC</item>
    <item>57,CO</item>
    <item>269,KM</item>
    <item>242,CG</item>
    <item>243,CD</item>
    <item>682,CK</item>
    <item>506,CR</item>
    <item>385,HR</item>
    <item>53,CU</item>
    <item>357,CY</item>
    <item>420,CZ</item>
    <item>45,DK</item>
    <item>253,DJ</item>
    <item>670,TL</item>
    <item>593,EC</item>
    <item>20,EG</item>
    <item>503,SV</item>
    <item>240,GQ</item>
    <item>291,ER</item>
    <item>372,EE</item>
    <item>251,ET</item>
    <item>500,FK</item>
    <item>298,FO</item>
    <item>679,FJ</item>
    <item>358,FI</item>
    <item>33,FR</item>
    <item>689,PF</item>
    <item>241,GA</item>
    <item>220,GM</item>
    <item>995,GE</item>
    <item>49,DE</item>
    <item>233,GH</item>
    <item>350,GI</item>
    <item>30,GR</item>
    <item>299,GL</item>
    <item>502,GT</item>
    <item>224,GN</item>
    <item>245,GW</item>
    <item>592,GY</item>
    <item>509,HT</item>
    <item>504,HN</item>
    <item>852,HK</item>
    <item>36,HU</item>
    <item>91,IN</item>
    <item>62,ID</item>
    <item>98,IR</item>
    <item>964,IQ</item>
    <item>353,IE</item>
    <item>44,IM</item>
    <item>972,IL</item>
    <item>39,IT</item>
    <item>225,CI</item>
    <item>81,JP</item>
    <item>962,JO</item>
    <item>7,KZ</item>
    <item>254,KE</item>
    <item>686,KI</item>
    <item>965,KW</item>
    <item>996,KG</item>
    <item>856,LA</item>
    <item>371,LV</item>
    <item>961,LB</item>
    <item>266,LS</item>
    <item>231,LR</item>
    <item>218,LY</item>
    <item>423,LI</item>
    <item>370,LT</item>
    <item>352,LU</item>
    <item>853,MO</item>
    <item>389,MK</item>
    <item>261,MG</item>
    <item>265,MW</item>
    <item>60,MY</item>
    <item>960,MV</item>
    <item>223,ML</item>
    <item>356,MT</item>
    <item>692,MH</item>
    <item>222,MR</item>
    <item>230,MU</item>
    <item>262,YT</item>
    <item>52,MX</item>
    <item>691,FM</item>
    <item>373,MD</item>
    <item>377,MC</item>
    <item>976,MN</item>
    <item>382,ME</item>
    <item>212,MA</item>
    <item>258,MZ</item>
    <item>264,NA</item>
    <item>674,NR</item>
    <item>977,NP</item>
    <item>31,NL</item>
    <item>599,AN</item>
    <item>687,NC</item>
    <item>64,NZ</item>
    <item>505,NI</item>
    <item>227,NE</item>
    <item>234,NG</item>
    <item>683,NU</item>
    <item>850,KP</item>
    <item>47,NO</item>
    <item>968,OM</item>
    <item>92,PK</item>
    <item>680,PW</item>
    <item>507,PA</item>
    <item>675,PG</item>
    <item>595,PY</item>
    <item>51,PE</item>
    <item>63,PH</item>
    <item>870,PN</item>
    <item>48,PL</item>
    <item>351,PT</item>
    <item>1,PR</item>
    <item>974,QA</item>
    <item>40,RO</item>
    <item>7,RU</item>
    <item>250,RW</item>
    <item>590,BL</item>
    <item>685,WS</item>
    <item>378,SM</item>
    <item>239,ST</item>
    <item>966,SA</item>
    <item>221,SN</item>
    <item>381,RS</item>
    <item>248,SC</item>
    <item>232,SL</item>
    <item>65,SG</item>
    <item>421,SK</item>
    <item>386,SI</item>
    <item>677,SB</item>
    <item>252,SO</item>
    <item>27,ZA</item>
    <item>82,KR</item>
    <item>34,ES</item>
    <item>94,LK</item>
    <item>290,SH</item>
    <item>508,PM</item>
    <item>249,SD</item>
    <item>597,SR</item>
    <item>268,SZ</item>
    <item>46,SE</item>
    <item>41,CH</item>
    <item>963,SY</item>
    <item>886,TW</item>
    <item>992,TJ</item>
    <item>255,TZ</item>
    <item>66,TH</item>
    <item>228,TG</item>
    <item>690,TK</item>
    <item>676,TO</item>
    <item>216,TN</item>
    <item>90,TR</item>
    <item>993,TM</item>
    <item>688,TV</item>
    <item>971,AE</item>
    <item>256,UG</item>
    <item>44,GB</item>
    <item>380,UA</item>
    <item>598,UY</item>
    <item>1,US</item>
    <item>998,UZ</item>
    <item>678,VU</item>
    <item>39,VA</item>
    <item>58,VE</item>
    <item>84,VN</item>
    <item>681,WF</item>
    <item>967,YE</item>
    <item>260,ZM</item>
    <item>263,ZW</item>
</string-array>
```

And finally, to get the good country code, add this code to your project.

```
public static String GetCountryZipCode(Context context) throw Exception
{
    // Get the country ISO
    TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    String countryIso = manager.getSimCountryIso().toUpperCase();

    // Load resources containing the country codes list
    String[] countryCodes = this.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.CountryCodes);

    // Try to find what we need
    for(int i=0; i<countryCodes.length; i++)
    {
        String[] line = countryCodes[i].split(",");
        if (line.length != 2) throw new Exception("Resource file looks like invalid.");

        // We have found something interesting
        if (line[1].trim().equals(countryIso.trim()))
        return line[0];
    }

    // Nothing was found
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of approach for this...

**Method 1:** Store all the country codes manually in a file and use them in your application.

Here you can update the codes only during updates..

**Method 2:** Store in your remote database and call them as per your need using http request..

Here this can be edited at any times as you wish

Its fully on your interest and need...

Try to provide more details in question..

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this [webservice](http://www.webservicex.net/country.asmx) for getting all the country names and also you can use the obtained country names in the same webservice by passing them to the method `GetISD` using http methods or REST/SOAP
*** And you have to parse each and every results and store it in a local database and then use them for your needs ***